# getPolarisMap() returns null even though a new Instance

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I'm working on a Fragment nesting a map using the *`Polaris`* library.

Until now, I've been able to get the Google Map on my Fragment but for a reason I cannot explain, I'm not able to get the map, even thought I create dynamically, it is not null, but when I try to get the PolarisMap using the *`getPolarisMap`* on the fragment it returns null.

My fragment is hosted by a ViewPager itself host inside a *`SherlockFragment`*.